# How to Live Stream YouTube without Audio

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, live-streaming, ip-camera

I have two IP cam and a computer with `ffmpeg` to re-stream them to YouTube.

**First Cam**

It has *Video and Audio*. I can re-stream to YouTube successfully with this command.

`ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.aaa.bbb:554/ch0_1.h264 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 2048k -vb 400k -maxrate 800k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -g 30 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<YouTube_key>`

**Second Cam**

It has *Video* only. However, with both commands below, I can't stream to YouTube. (although the `ffmpeg` process is running well)

`ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.aaa.ccc/Streaming/Channels/102 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 2048k -vb 400k -maxrate 800k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -g 30 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<YouTube_key>`

or

`ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.aaa.ccc/Streaming/Channels/102 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 2048k -vb 400k -maxrate 800k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -g 30 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<YouTube_key>`

I've test both camera's stream first using FLV, and they work well. So, the issue is not the URL of IP camera.

From what I understand, YouTube define [stream as audio-video content](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). However, what if the source only has Video.

So, my question:

**How to live stream YouTube without audio, specially from an IP cam?**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate a dummy audio and try

```
ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.aaa.ccc/Streaming/Channels/102
       -f lavfi -i anullsrc
       -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 2048k -vb 400k -maxrate 800k
       -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -g 30 -r 30
       -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k
       -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<YouTube_key>
```